# Beacon proxy that a user can take control of

Tags: proxy-contracts

I have a complex proxy ownership model to implement and I want to know if there is an existing suite that has a similar model, or if existing libraries (e.g. OpenZeppelin) support this.

1. A central authority (factory) controls a proxy (beacon) and is able to upgrade the implementation of multiple proxies.
2. A proxy is owned by the deployer. The deployer is able to break the beacon reference to point to their own implementation.

Initial state looks like the below:
[image: Initial State]

When the Factory performs an upgrade:
[image: Factory Upgrade State]

When the User performs an upgrade:
[image: User Upgrade State]

My current thinking is to update the Beacon Proxy implementation from OpenZeppelin and change the `_implementation` function to a user set implementation if set, otherwise fail over to the Beacon. I want to know if there is an existing library/etc that does this already.